# Node usb printer

Tags: node.js, usb, printers, thermal-printer

[image]Anyone knows how to set-up a USB printer for node js. I m not able to configure the interface for it .
Here is my code

```
enter code here const ThermalPrinter = require("../node-thermal-printer").printer;
                const Types = require("../node-thermal-printer").types;
                const electron = typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.versions && 
                                  !!process.versions.electron;

                async function testConnection () { 

                let printer = new ThermalPrinter({
                type: 'star',                                    
                interface: "Gold" //name of the printer
                });
                printer.print("hi");
                let isConnected = await printer.isPrinterConnected() 
                console.log("Printer connected:", isConnected);
                }
                 testConnection();
```

Comment: According to the npm description article, `interface: "Gold"` is written as `interface: "printer:Gold"`, isn't it? [Interface options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thermal-printer#interface-options)

Comment: After setting this it is saying cannot able to find driver set for it. Even I tried setting the interface as "printer: Gold" still got stuck into the driver set

Comment: As in the same explanation, is it necessary to set using [node-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer) or [electron-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-printer)?

Comment: yes, it is as I am using node-thermal-printer.

Comment: In the description of node-thermal-printer, it seems that it is necessary to specify `driver:` in the definition of `let printer = new ThermalPrinter` or do `setPrinterDriver()` in addition, so please add it and try it.

Comment: what path should I add as a driver while using a USB printer?

Comment: For the time being, try something with node-printer or electron-printer alone, and if you can do it, try using it from node-thermal-printer. [How to print a docx file to a printer using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50817153/9014308), [is it possible to print an image with node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23437804/9014308), [Use Node js to to print data to thermal printer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59225919/9014308), [Receipt thermal printer in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53254089/9014308)

Comment: I have read and tried all of the above I am able to print using a Lan printer but for a USB printer, it's not working.

Comment: After that, try these forks [devarthurribeiro/thermal-printer](https://github.com/devarthurribeiro/thermal-printer), or replace them with [song940/node-escpos](https://github.com/song940/node-escpos), including node-thermal-printer.

Comment: Yes I tried both of them also still got stuck in USB printer..

Comment: There is an example that you can print with npm-escpos, so why not set the printer to serial port mode and install the corresponding device driver? [Create receipt with escpos package and Serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65575304/9014308), [Epson thermal printer status from NodeJS with ESC/POS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62176249/9014308)

Answer (score 5):

The error that jumps out at me is in your interface.
if you use a usb port I advise you to start by making a print sharing and then to configure your node-termal-printer file by modifying the value "interface"

1. first you do a printer sharing
   [image]
2. you modify the value "interface" indicating the path and the shared printer

   ```
        `interface: '//localhost/printer',`
   ```

Comment: Hello does `node-thermal-printer` package work with Chinese point of sale thermal printers?

Comment: we need to test what is the model?

Comment: I tried the package with the x printer q371u and it worked fine. I learned that most of the Chinese thermal printers use the Epson schema.

Answer (score 0):

install your printer and simply test on windows that it works,
remember to install the manufacturer's drivers,

then you simply indicate the port you used (in interface: 'com1', or 'com3' ...)

example

```
 let printer = new ThermalPrinter({
  type: PrinterTypes.EPSON,
  interface: '//./COM3'
});
```